# How can I list all CPAN modules depending on a given module?

Tags: perl, cpan

How can I list all CPAN modules depending on a given module? For example, create a list of modules using Class::Workflow?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's two valid questions about dependencies:

- What modules does the given module require?
- The reversed question: Which modules depend on the given module?

For the former, the authoritative but non-recursive answer is *usually* to look at the META.yml file that's part of most modern distributions. If there is no such file, you may try looking at the Makefile.PL or Build.PL build tools that ship with it. If you want to know *all* dependencies and not just the direct ones, cf. ghostdog74's answer. Specifically, David Cantrell's ['CPANDeps'](http://deps.cpantesters.org/) is very, very handy.

Obviously, the latter question is impossible to answer by inspecting the module itself. If you don't want to grep an unpacked [minicpan](http://search.cpan.org/dist/CPAN-Mini), the best solution is something like the "[used by](http://cpants.perl.org/dist/used_by/Class-XSAccessor)" section of a module's [CPANTS](http://cpants.perl.org) entry.

Comment: The last time I checked, the CPANTS information wasn't all that great. It assumed the names of modules from their path under lib/, so some of my modules appear to be quite popular. See, for instance, Test::URI.

Comment: CPANdeps will also go in reverse.  Right now it only goes up one level, but making it a tree is on the to-do list.

Answer (score 6):

you can use a module such as [CPAN::Dependency](http://search.cpan.org/~saper/CPAN-Dependency-0.15/lib/CPAN/Dependency.pm), or try [this](http://deps.cpantesters.org/) online , among many others.

Answer (score 1):

I’ve found [CPAN::Dependency](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?CPAN::Dependency) and [CPAN::FindDependencies](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?CPAN::FindDependencies) on CPAN, they might help you.

Answer (score 1):

Some other options:

- [Module::ScanDeps](http://search.cpan.org/~smueller/Module-ScanDeps-0.96/lib/Module/ScanDeps.pm)
- [Perl::PrereqScanner](http://search.cpan.org/~rjbs/Perl-PrereqScanner-0.100521/lib/Perl/PrereqScanner.pm)